# "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame" while working directly from files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file://localhost/Users/bobrodes2/Documents/PD%20Manager%20UI/3.7/FieldContactAddEdit.html# from frame with URL file://localhost/Users/bobrodes2/Documents/PD%20Manager%20UI/3.7/fieldcontacteditactions_modal.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I've done my reading, and I can't figure out how it is that these two files could be different domains (or ports).  They're both in the same folder of the same machine!  The latter file is a modal using jQuery's dialog() method, and we're setting up the modal as an iframe.  Not sure what code will be helpful, but will be glad to post any requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start a simple web server.

If you're on OS X or otherwise have Python installed, just `cd` into the directory you want to use as root and use...

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html).

Comment: cd into which directory, please?  (I'm on OS X.)

Comment: @BobRodes The root directory of your files that you want to be the root of your server.

Comment: Ok, so I did this: BobR-iMac:3.7 bobrodes2$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ... Now how do I reference my html file?  I tried http://0.0.0.0/myfile.html and it doesn't work.

Comment: @BobRodes Try http://0.0.0.0:8000/myfile.html You're no longer on the `file` protocol and you need to specify the port.

Comment: Got it!!  I must have closed it up in the terminal.  Thank you!!  To clarify, you need to leave the command open in terminal rather than breaking out of it and doing other stuff like looking at files.

Comment: @BobRodes Yes, if you close that running Python program, the server can no longer accept requests. You can send it to background however with Ctrl+Z, view it there with `bg` and bring it back with `fg`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, files served through file:// URIs are considered under different domains.

To disable (temporarily) the same-origin policy under Chrome, for development purposes, try: http://joshuamcginnis.com/2011/02/28/how-to-disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/

The best alternative is to start a http server locally.

Answer (score 2):

It's a browser security issue. Chrome, for instance, will deny permissions to any file served with the `file://` protocol.

So as an example, if you're trying to make AJAX calls by opening a connection to `file://c/myfiles/mytext.txt`, Chrome is going to throw up a security violation (because why should the browser be able to read a visitor's filesystem and read in file information as text, to store in a cookie, or send off to be tracked).

Same deal with iFrames, and with editing canvas data if the canvas is being used to hold a picture loaded from a different domain.

The solution is to set up a webserver.  Any language at all -- I'd suggest PHP given that the install-time for a PHP server is now next to nil, thanks to WAMP/EasyPHP/PHP5.4's built-in webserver, et cetera...

...but as soon as you're serving from an IP addres, or something which resolves to an IP address (even `0.0.0.0`), that origin-policy should go away.